# Creating bi-polar signal from IC's

Tags: transistors, cmos, bipolar

[image]

I'm trying to create a bi-polar square wave from a flip flop but all I get is a positive result. It never goes below GND. I know the second (lower) transistor gets positively biased and maybe this is the cause.

I tried various things, NPN, PNP, combo.

How it's done?

[Fahlstad simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWK0CcZEGYBsYAcXIB2MLJBSEMihAUwFowwAoMBJQgJgo23DlxA8sUSkwBKILBwAsgrAITTZ2ARA584lERRgImAdxC4SIaZtzSBZnQaOXT5%209KyzIti1ZchCkWc9e2Pn5eQYK8boahQt5cYcJuAC7grOpKqlwUaSIQYLCsimCEpCgctHQYYOq5KGgc8oUcGET0FVWaACY0AGYAhgCuADYJTEm4KMLWIChKDjrgyFhNkKUcjTUohCi4SAyw0mhYpLgchBjSGBognb2Dw4a4GOrRxsLREVMzGBZTJYLf7zUnt9AaZHlBbNM-CZxpkTACCKZoQiVODDDC5AJ0RgEOp3uhIAJHhQQUTwQAnD7KWKQkCleIaNwUkHndTM8bZeDiH6pdkgxSuERmEAMXHaaB6CQ0umU8C-OZCyraZB6CljCaOKyaCj4xl2Qm8NVxDlwWxSZTyGLcC3vB5PA32N4Q5EW9CcDHggDyyV87sY3xRNlG7OiJX19IYwpgOAQOsInE25DAKCm0HwtX2m04bFwhEu136QxYUj4bukJldqS86nztzoAxo7XmcxgkGYJCq6GCskYPrLwmr3QLCTrDabYtbTApFcRwmnAckuF1Pahs877oo8jxa5Rc%20tTAA5iXK92iKlF9oD96u1fTOebGjPtTPjjUTLsayOISXwDP4JqcjYnhbh-24b8mAAe3mCAKAADx6RMACMtBgaDaWQ%20YLhbUpwUgnIRDgxN1CQFCMPQiBMNgbCKCo5CmCAA)

Cooked from Spehro Pefhany's answer
[image]
[enter link description here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWK0CcZEGYBsYAcXIB2MLJBSEMihAUwFowwAoMBJQgJgo23DlxA8sUSkwBKILBwAsgrAITTZ2ARA584lERRgImAdxC4SIaZtzSBZnQaOXT5%209KyzIti1ZchCkWc9e2Pn5eQYK8boahQt5cYcIRRhjq0cbC0W4ATnYCKShp4aY%20CVLK8jHcZQm4SXHZtZlGebW4TRycIujwTFktwm3qvSBcAhSdcEwALo197ShKQ%200UDCAoqCjr64QoPuhYKEh0WLDoKBjo0mBb67R0qpoAJjQAZgCGAK4ANhO2c7IcCMJfkNICMfvNhtNgaCJIMIYMwBwRiIzFodMg9IYgYiBECMAh1AlcfiNDliYT5nj1EDrFBuit5jTqV4KNIikwAOaQywUQb4pFuKadATYvgAoa4JEQOirDYbXAIYhcODCOgwRgWfYgmSECWs9YaECPV6fb6C-gOUaQMU0pYQMDQaSIq5zK3VQgIYz0QggVXQdXSTW4bW6q4Go3vL62IXiu4gwRkqPmykki20wzoMUYCyitIJ9NWtK%20HPxglgv5xjN9OMJStQ4v9NP04KyWv%20Rutrytkw1gslvgSvtuADy-dJ6kYxOTNkxDK81Kabgk88B8z52gcPqQaN0dPW6kUsj3plwaNZ4x6Jg4MiMJku8XAJ7cAHtwK%20KAAPF7kMAAI1RfpEfcOkEZBIH%20WkXztERP2-IC1VfDBUQQ0DwO4RDqFpIA)

Comment: You need some level translation or maybe an op-amp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use emitter followers. Emitter followers have no voltage gain so this will not work. You can try adding a stage in front with voltage gain:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4SyxE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Shown assuming the FF supply is < 12V. If your flip-flop has 12V output you can eliminate Q1 and R1.

Q1 changes the 0/5V input (FF output) to +12/0V approximately (at the collector of Q1)

Q2 changes the +12/0V to -12/+12V

Q3 and Q4 provide current gain, especially for the -12V level which otherwise would just be R4 pulling the output low.

[image]

Comment: the flip flop's from Falstad simulator are 5 Volt, but otherwise working perfectly if you change everything to 5V, witch is basically what a want a 10 V.p.p signal, thank you.
Updated image.

Comment: @NaturalDemon Sounds like a new question (you can link to this one).